# Difference in creating a button using button tag and using an anchor tag using css

Tags: html, css

Hi everyone i have created a button using a tag and designed it using class 'mybutton'

```
<a class="col-md-3 mybutton" id="view_stock">View</a>
```

css:

```
.myButton {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #3e7327;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #3e7327;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #3e7327;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #77b55a), color-stop(1, #72b352));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#77b55a', endColorstr='#72b352',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#77b55a;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #4b8f29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #5b8a3c;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #72b352), color-stop(1, #77b55a));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#72b352', endColorstr='#77b55a',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#72b352;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

but when i changed `<a>` tag in to a `<button>` tag its not working i don't know why?
can any one help.............

Comment: ***changed tag in to a tag*** what exactly does this mean? That's why many many questions asked in SO are very hard to understand.

Comment: @KingKing the OP means anchor tag.

Comment: is there any problem in using <a> tag for submit function while using it in jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2z6Ez/)***</kbd>

You did a typographic mistake in mentioning the class it must be `myButton` rather than `mybutton`

*HTML*

```
<a class="col-md-3 myButton" id="view_stock">View</a>
<button class="myButton">Button</button>
```

Comment: I couldn't see that. +1

Comment: after changing that too i dnt get the result

Comment: @user3593694 it works in fiddle that means it is correct, you must check all related codes... Why don't you post your complete code..